# getting doubled queries laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using laravel clockwork to monitor my queries

in my controller I have

```
public function index(){
    $errorFound = false;
    $error = ['error' => 'No Monitor Found'];
    $urls = $this->url->with('url_status','latestUrlStatus','users');
    if (request()->has('q')) {
        $keyword = '%'.request()->get('q').'%';
        $builder = $urls->where('description', 'like', $keyword);
        $builder->count() ? $urls = $builder : $errorFound = true;
    }
   return $errorFound === false ? UrlsResource::collection($urls->latest()->paginate(5)->appends(request()->query())) : $error;
}
```

on my laravel clockwork im getting 
doubled queries

[image]

is it normal? if it is a problem how can I fix this? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem. All of those queries are expected.

The first query (select users...) isn't from the code you've shown. It came from TrustProxies.

The second query (select count()) is from `$builder->count()`.

All the rest of the queries come from `$urls->latest()->paginate(5)`. The first thing `paginate()` does is run a `count()` query (the third query) to get the total number of records. Then it moves on to call the real queries.

In this case, the fourth query is your main query for all your urls, the fifth query is the query to eager load your `url_status` relationship, the sixth query is the query to eager load your `latestUrlStatus` relationship, and the seventh query is the query to eager load your `users` relationship.

Comment: is it normal because the SELECT count(*) as aggregate FROM `urls` WHERE `description` like '%%' and SELECT * FROM `url_status` WHERE `url_status`.`url_id` in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') ORDER BY `created_at` DESC became twice

Comment: @Beginner Yes, that's what I explained in my answer. The first "select count()" is from calling `$builder->count()`, the second "select count()" comes from inside the `paginate()` function. The first `url_status` query comes from eager loading your `url_status` relationship. The second `url_status` query comes from eager loading your `latestUrlStatus` query.